# Export Import Term Sets with PnP

Tags: taxonomy, pnp-powershell, pnp, term-set

I'd like to export a term set from one SP 2016 environment to another. I wanted to use this command: `Export-PnPTaxonomy` as in here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/export-pnptaxonomy?view=sharepoint-ps

But it exports the result as .txt, if I want to use this command: `Import-PnPTermSet` as in here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/import-pnptermset?view=sharepoint-ps it expects a .csv file.

How would I use PnP to export/import term sets? either export/import a .txt file or .csv file.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and had to use the `Export-PnPTermGroupToXml` to get the export of all Term Groups in the required XML format to import.

You can get further details [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/export-pnptermgrouptoxml?view=sharepoint-ps)